# How do I use Google IAP for authenticating to JupyterHub?

Tags: jwt, jupyterhub, google-iap

I have Google's [Identity-Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/) configured for my JupyterHub application, and would like to use it to authenticate my users. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

Google passes signed JWT headers to applications with IAP in front of them, as described in [Securing your app with signed headers](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto). You can use [mogthesprog/jwtauthenticator](https://github.com/mogthesprog/jwtauthenticator) to enable JWT-based authentication in JupyterHub.

### Configuring through `jupyterhub_config.py`

Once `jupyterhub-jwtauthenticator` is installed on your JupyterHub server, add the following configuration:

#### jupyterhub_config.py

```
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'jwtauthenticator.jwtauthenticator.JSONWebTokenAuthenticator'
c.JSONWebTokenAuthenticator.header_name = 'x-goog-iap-jwt-assertion'
c.JSONWebTokenAuthenticator.header_is_authorization = False
c.JSONWebTokenAuthenticator.expected_audience = '/projects/PROJECT_NUMBER/global/backendServices/SERVICE_ID`
c.JSONWebTokenAuthenticator.username_claim_field = 'email'

# Retrieved from https://www.gstatic.com/iap/verify/public_key
c.JSONWebTokenAuthenticator.secret = """
{
   "2nMJtw" : "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE9e1x7YRZg53A5zIJ0p2ZQ9yTrgPL\nGIf4ntOk+4O2R2+ryIObueyenPXE92tYG1NlKjDNyJLc7tsxi0UUnyxpig==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
   "6BEeoA" : "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAElmi1hJdqtbvdX1INOf5B9dWvkydY\noowHUXiw8ELWzk/YHESNr8vXQoyOuLOEtLZeCQbFkeLUqxYp1sTArKNu/A==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
   "FAWt5w" : "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE8auUAdTS54HmUuIabrTKvWawxmbs\n81kdbzQMV/Tae0EhLgin8qnJ4lklJrxEzksXg5OtBuzE62DIj+CePN20Pg==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
   "LYyP2g" : "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAESlXFFkJ3JxMsXyXNrqzE3ozl/091\n3PmNbccLLWfeQFUYtJqGtl8ESuYxRwc/QwZp5Wcl0HCq6GuFDx4/Tk18Ig==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
   "f9R3yg" : "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAESqCmEwytkqG6tL6a2GTQGmSNI4jH\nYo5MeDUs7DpETVhCXXLIFrLg2sZvNqw8SGnnonLoeqgOSqRdjJBGt4I6jQ==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
}
"""
```

### Configuring through `zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s`

If you're using `zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s` to provision JupyterHub in a Kubernetes cluster, you will first need to bake the `jupyterhub-jwtauthenticator` package into your hub image.

With the following `Dockerfile` and `cloudbuild.yaml` in a directory, execute `gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .` using the appropriate project.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM jupyterhub/k8s-hub:0.7.0

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir jupyterhub-jwtauthenticator
```

#### cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'pull', 'docker.io/jupyterhub/k8s-hub:0.7.0' ]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/k8s-hub', '.' ]
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/k8s-hub'
```

#### values.yaml

```
hub:
  image:
    name: gcr.io/<project>/k8s-hub
    tag: latest
auth:
  type: custom
  custom:
    className: 'jwtauthenticator.jwtauthenticator.JSONWebTokenAuthenticator'
    config:
      header_name: x-goog-iap-jwt-assertion
      header_is_authorization: false
      expected_audience: '/projects/PROJECT_NUMBER/global/backendServices/SERVICE_ID'
      username_claim_field: email
      # Retrieved from https://www.gstatic.com/iap/verify/public_key
      secret: |
        {
           "2nMJtw" : "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE9e1x7YRZg53A5zIJ0p2ZQ9yTrgPL\nGIf4ntOk+4O2R2+ryIObueyenPXE92tYG1NlKjDNyJLc7tsxi0UUnyxpig==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
           "6BEeoA" : "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAElmi1hJdqtbvdX1INOf5B9dWvkydY\noowHUXiw8ELWzk/YHESNr8vXQoyOuLOEtLZeCQbFkeLUqxYp1sTArKNu/A==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
           "FAWt5w" : "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE8auUAdTS54HmUuIabrTKvWawxmbs\n81kdbzQMV/Tae0EhLgin8qnJ4lklJrxEzksXg5OtBuzE62DIj+CePN20Pg==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
           "LYyP2g" : "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAESlXFFkJ3JxMsXyXNrqzE3ozl/091\n3PmNbccLLWfeQFUYtJqGtl8ESuYxRwc/QwZp5Wcl0HCq6GuFDx4/Tk18Ig==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
           "f9R3yg" : "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAESqCmEwytkqG6tL6a2GTQGmSNI4jH\nYo5MeDUs7DpETVhCXXLIFrLg2sZvNqw8SGnnonLoeqgOSqRdjJBGt4I6jQ==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
        }
```

### Retrieving IAP public keys automatically

If you don't want to bake the public keys for IAP JWT tokens into your configuration, you can retrieve these at run-time through your `jupyterhub_config.py`, or as `extraConfig` in the helm chart.

#### `jupyterhub_config.py`

```
from urllib import request
c.JSONWebTokenLocalAuthenticator.secret = request.urlopen('https://www.gstatic.com/iap/verify/public_key').read()
```

For `zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s`:

#### `values.yaml`

```
hub:
  extraConfig:
    config-jwtauthenticator: |
      from urllib import request
      c.JSONWebTokenLocalAuthenticator.secret = request.urlopen('https://www.gstatic.com/iap/verify/public_key').read()
```